# Firebase Authorization with Swift 3.0 not working

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-authentication

Since updating to Swift 3.0 even with the correct password I receive the incorrect message. Has anyone had this problem with authorizing users on Firebase?

```
@IBAction func LoginToAccount(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    if let email = emailLogin.text, let password = passwordLogin.text {

    FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: {
        (user, error) in


        if error != nil{
            print("Incorrect")
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Incorrect Email or Password.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(action)
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }else{
            if error == nil   {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "AdminSegue", sender: self)

               }
            }
        })
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *not working*?

Comment: it will be useful if you show us what the error message is.

Comment: What I mean is even with the correct password I am just getting the message string "Incorrect email or password". Worked fine before updating to Swift 3.0

Comment: Okay so really strange. The login works fine on the device it just doesn't work in the simulator. This is only since updating to Xcode 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could create an email and have problem with sign in then it would be like my case. Just check your keychain accessibility from yourproject.xcodeproject -> Capabilities -> keychain Sharing - > On if it is  off.

Answer (score 1):

After some research this is apparently an issue with Simulator 10.0 not allowing Firebase to write values to the keychain. Something they are working on apparently but it doesn't affect app on actual device.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure the user has been created initially, because you have to create a user first and then sign in using the created user.

```
@IBAction func LoginToAccount(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    if let email = emailLogin.text, let password = passwordLogin.text {

       FIRAuth.auth()!.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { user, error in
       if error == nil {
       FIRAuth.auth()!.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, , completion: { (user, error) in


          if error != nil{
             print("Incorrect")
             let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Incorrect Email or Password.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
             let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
             alert.addAction(action)
             self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
           } else {
             if error == nil   {
             self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "AdminSegue", sender: self)
           }
         }
       })
      }
   }    
}
```